# How can i determine the width of a drawn string?

Tags: c#, drawstring, valueconverter

I'm drawing a string using the following:

```
g.DrawString(somestring, somefont, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), X where it starts, Y where it starts));
```

Problem:

Sometimes I want to align the drawn string on the `left side` of a `line`.
But, it doesn't work if I don't know what the string length will be.

Possible but noob solution:

Count the number of chars, multiply for a trial and error value, and subtract it on X position, like this:

```
string somestring = Convert.ToString(Math.Round(10 * somevalue) / 10) + "m";
int stringcount1 = somestring.Count();
g.DrawString(somestring, somefont, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), X -stringcount1 * trialanderrorvalue, Y));
```

This doesn't work because, as you can guess, I'm creating a number, and that number can have a `decimal separator` or not.

And that is the problem, because the decimal separator is not a very wide character, but still counts, it will be sending my string neptune-far from the line. Or I can get a decent trial and error value for a number with a decimal separator, and if eventually the number doesn't have a decimal separator it will be above the line (and ruin the drawing).

Any hints? Possibly forcing the string to have a `,0` in the case that the number is a integer?

Edit:

I've now created a method that will return a`SizeF` object given a string and a font.

```
    static SizeF MeasureStringMin(string measureString, Font stringFont, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //// Set up string. 
        //string measureString = "Measure String";
        //Font stringFont = new Font("Arial", 16);

        // Measure string.
        SizeF stringSize = new SizeF();

        stringSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(measureString, stringFont);

        return stringSize;
    }
```

The problem is that when I recall this function using something like

```
SizeF stringSize = new SizeF();
stringSize = MeasureStringMin(somestring, somefont, ????)
```

I never know what to put in the third variable, hints on this? Why do I need the `PaintEventArgs`?

Comment: Which exact library are you using? WPF, XNA, GDI? Or more specifically, what's the type of the `g` variable?

Comment: Always assume that that operator exists and if not add .00 ?

Comment: `g` will be a `Graphics` object - this is winforms / GDI.

Comment: @JoachimGotzes, yes that's a possibility, but a complex one, also, could easily get messy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [`MeasureString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring.aspx) function! Use it to get the exact dimensions of the string before you draw it, and adjust the position accordingly.

Comment: I've updated the question, and there's a simple issue I'm sure you can easily clear out, can you take a look?

Comment: You need the PaintEventArgs (`e`), because you're calling `e.Graphics.MeasureString`. You need a `Graphics` instance to call MeasureString on. You should be doing this in the `Paint` event handler, so you should have an `e` to pass along.

Comment: If you don't have a `PaintEventArgs` (because you're drawing on a bitmap or something), then you will still have a `Graphics` instance that you're drawing with, so just use that instead of `e.Graphics`. You might wish to change your method's signature to accept a `Graphics` object rather than a `PaintEventArgs`. That method is just a simple pass-through to MeasureString anyway though, so I would say you don't need it, really...